# TSQL Update table timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The sql in the stored procedure has several updates. I have fixed one and the one left is still timing out.

The table being updated has over 600000 records. The select statement in the sql runs fast when tested alone so it has to be the update part.

```
UPDATE tblPackage  
SET IsUpdated = 1,
    ShippingCost = (
        SELECT SUM(SC.ShippingCost)
        FROM tblShippingCost SC
        WHERE SC.PackageID = P.PackageID)
FROM tblShippingCost SC
    INNER JOIN tblPackage P ON P.PackageID = SC.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tblRunPackage RP ON RP.PackageID = P.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tblRun R ON R.RunID = RP.RunID
    INNER JOIN tblOrderItem OI ON OI.OrderItemID = R.OrderItemID
    INNER JOIN tblOrder O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE 
    O.InvoiceID IS NULL 
    AND SC.PackageID = P.PackageID
```

I welcome any and all suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: table have triggers ?

Comment: No, the table has not triggers

Comment: Why are you using the same alias twice? `tblShippingCost` in the correlated subquery should *not* have the alias `SC`.  And why do you have `AND SC.PackageID = P.PackageID` in the WHERE clause?  What is that supposed to do?  You've already specified that in the JOIN condition, and in the correlated subquery's WHERE clause.

Comment: Share and/or look at the execution plan, that is the simplest and fastest way to identify performance issues with a query.

Answer (score 1):

You have joined tblshippingcost an extra time, this will not give the wrong result. But it will take more time joining and calculating. Try removing that part from your update like this:

```
UPDATE tblPackage  
SET
  IsUpdated = 1,
  ShippingCost = (
       SELECT SUM(SC.ShippingCost)
       FROM tblShippingCost SC
       WHERE SC.PackageID = P.PackageID
     )
FROM 
    tblPackage P
INNER JOIN 
  tblRunPackage RP ON RP.PackageID = P.PackageID
INNER JOIN
  tblRun R ON R.RunID = RP.RunID
INNER JOIN 
  tblOrderItem OI ON OI.OrderItemID = R.OrderItemID
INNER JOIN 
  tblOrder O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE 
    O.InvoiceID IS NULL
```

Comment: The tblPackage reference would fail in tblShippingCost is not referenced again. FROM tblPackage P ON P.PackageID = SC.PackageID will fail.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE tblPackage  
SET IsUpdated = 1,
    ShippingCost = SUM(SC.ShippingCost)
FROM tblShippingCost SC
    INNER JOIN tblPackage P ON P.PackageID = SC.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tblRunPackage RP ON RP.PackageID = P.PackageID
    INNER JOIN tblRun R ON R.RunID = RP.RunID
    INNER JOIN tblOrderItem OI ON OI.OrderItemID = R.OrderItemID
    INNER JOIN tblOrder O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE 
    O.InvoiceID IS NULL 
    AND SC.PackageID = P.PackageID
```

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement